# Execute symfony command in bash script

Tags: bash, cron, command, apache2, symfony4

I can't get to execute symfony command in bash script when I run it in `cron`.
When I execute the .sh script by hand everything is working fine.

in my bash file the command is executed like this:

```
/usr/bin/php -q /var/www/pww24/bin/console pww24:import asari $office > /dev/null
```

I run the scripts from root, the `cron` is set to root as well. For the test i set files permissions to 777 and added `+x` for execution.

the bash script executes fine. It acts like it's skipping the command but from logs i can see that the code is executed

Comment: Where is your $office var defined? Can you redirect the output to a file? This will be a nice indicator of what is happening when the job is running as cron. You may also need to redirect stderr with 2>&1

Comment: @itChi  $office works fine as I can see it in logs. Plus When I hard code the variable it doesn't work either

Comment: Do you have full path in `$office` variable?

Comment: @RomeoNinov $office is a simple string and while executing it from cron it works fine - I can see it in logs, plus the rest of the bash script depends on it and that works fine as well

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that symfony system variables that I have stored on server are not enough. When you start to execute the command from command line its fine, but when using Cron you need them in .env file. Turned out that in the proces of countinous integrations I only got `.env.dist` file and I've to make the `.env` file anyways. 
Additionaly I've added two lines to cron:

```
PATH=~/bin:/usr/bin/:/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

and run my command like this from the bash file:

```
sudo /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/pww24/bin/console pww24:import asari $office > /dev/null
```